# Collocation: Rates are large/small or high/low?

Tags: word-usage, collocation

What is the proper adjective for rates?

"..the learning rate is low/high.." 
or 
"..the learning rate is small/large.."

It seems that there are different opinions:

> Numbers can be described using the metaphor of size (large vs small) or height (high vs low).
>   <sub>Answer to [What's the difference between “large share” and “high share”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/216968/312090)</sub>

> “Large” and “small” are generally used to express variations or changes in size, dimensions, or mass. “High” and “low” are usually used to express levels or numerical values. “Large” and “small” are often mistakenly used where “high” and “low” would be better.
>   <sub>Springer.com: [Large/small/high/low](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/journal-author/large-small-high-low/1350)</sub>

Comment: Hello! Some dictionaries have examples of uses which might help - have you found examples of either 'high/low' or 'small/large' anywhere?

Comment: I dont see why a question about collocations is inappropriate. This is about English usage, right?

Comment: It isn't inappropriate, but see the close reason 'Please include the research you’ve done'

Comment: I've done my research and it was a simple question. I am not new to stackexchange. It is a bit frustrating. @marcellothearcane thanks anyway for the feedback

Comment: With the added sources (which I just quoted for convenience & to avoid link rot), I think this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford Collocations Dictionary suggests **high/low** for the 'speed/frequency' aspect of **rate** (the other aspect there is 'amount of money'). And also the adjectives are suggested: *constant, expected, regular, steady, slow, fast, rapid, alarming, phenomenal, ever-increasing, rocketing*, etc. In **no** aspect *large* or *small* are suggested (I guess those words are more typical for *pure numbers* of something).

An example of using **high/low** with **learning rate**.

https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-learning-rates-and-how-it-improves-performance-in-deep-learning-d0d4059c1c10

A picture of a graph from that page with definitions of different *learning rates* (**high/low/good**):

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/0*uIa_Dz3czXO5iWyI.